# Using + in rev into ivy.xml is not working

Tags: java, dependencies, ivy

Working with Ivy to manage all my dependencies in my project and then whenever I add + (plus) in rev attribute into ivy.xml is not working.

```
<dependency org="com.*****.*********" name="im-framework" rev="0.0.1+">
   <artifact name="im-framework-main" type="jar" conf="compile->compile" />
   <artifact name="im-framework-test" type="jar" conf="test->default" />
   <exclude name="log4j-over-slf4j" />
</dependency>
```

Error message:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Impossible to resolve dependencies of com.*****.*******#im-web;0.0.1    ivy.xml    /Project Unknown Problem
```

When I remove it and add the version number it is working fine.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Try rev="0.0.+". Also what revisions are available in your repository? Perhaps nothing matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using dynamic revision here. Take a look at this:
http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html

Answer (score 0):

I added another Ivy.xml[*] library by right clicking in 
project -> properties -> Java build path -> Add Library -> IvyDE Managed Dependencies and it is working fine